# Query issue using Doctrine2 : Error: Expected end of string, got '.'

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to build a query using Doctrine2 QueryBuilder, but this is what I get :

`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 69: Error: Expected end of string, got '.'`

Here's the query :

`SELECT value FROM Stats\MESBundle\Entity\Valeur V WHERE code = SE.ENR.PRIM.FM.ZS`

I think the problem is that `SE.ENR.PRIM.FM.ZS` contains dots. But I can't change this code. Thus, I have to find a way to solve this without changing the code (which is a variable actually : $code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Mysql, when you use strings, you have to write it between two double-quotes.

The following code should work:

```
SELECT value FROM Stats\MESBundle\Entity\Valeur V WHERE code = "SE.ENR.PRIM.FM.ZS"
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT value FROM Stats\MESBundle\Entity\Valeur V WHERE code = 'SE.ENR.PRIM.FM.ZS'
```